# Going from Dreamweaver to VS Code - SASS Compilation

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, dreamweaver

I had been working on projects within Dreamweaver CC and have recently made the switch to VS Code and all was going well until it got to compiling assets.

Every time I try to save a .scss it is auto-compiled into .css seemingly by magic.

I did some digging and found that it had something to do with Dreamweaver.

```
Backtrace:
C:\xampp\htdocs\my-newable\resources\assets\sass\app.scss:2
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:314:in `visit_import'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `block in visit'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `visit'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:171:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:183:in `with_environment'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:170:in `visit_children'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:190:in `visit_root'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:161:in `visit'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:10:in `visit'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/engine.rb:290:in `render'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:400:in `run'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:63:in `process_result'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in `parse'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in `parse!'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/bin/sass:23:in `load'
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018/ruby/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

How can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel mix is just a wrapper around webpack. It really simplifies using webpack.

So in your example, you would just write:

```
mix.sass(path_to_main.scss, 'output_folder');
```

For automatic building, you can run watcher which will watch for changes in code and build it on change.

I suggest reading complete mix documentation on official site: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

Comment: Does VS code have an issue with partials? As when I save a partial it gets converted into a CSS file and all I'm doing is hitting save.

Comment: VS code has noting to do with laravel mix. You can disable all you VS part and just let webpack watch, watch your files for changes and convert scss files to css (and build js, ....)

Comment: It just confuses me as I haven't set anything up to auto-compile partials.

Comment: Watch free lesson from laracasts: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/14